# Where to put `r` alias for method `render` in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I my views I want to use `r` alias for method `render`.
Following code will do this stuff:

```
module ActionView
  # Make alias for :render method
  class Base
    alias_method :r, :render
  end
end
```

This it pretty handy and nice for me, however I want to ask, what is the best place for this particular snippet? Currently I put this to my `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`.

Comment: That's where I would put it.